# What does "to bite into life" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In [this ads](https://youtu.be/90uILQxT8SE?t=14s) of a brand of toothpaste, it says "... so you can bite into life without hesitation."

What does *to bite into life* mean here? Does it also have different meaning in different context?

I have searched in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. In the entry "life", I found the idiom "spring into life", which *looks* close, but I am not sure if they are related somehow or not. In the entry "bite", I cannot find anything rather than the literal meaning of "to bite into something".

Comment: It's advertising, so it can mean whatever you want it to mean. Providing it has a positive connotation, the toothpaste manufacturer will be happy. The motto *carpe diem* (seize the day) comes to mind.

Comment: Well, pangingilo is a "dentilo hypersensitivity" (as you imagine by watching the video) and yes, I suggest you to read the "bite into something" thread. It's advertising, anyway.